# Extracting in-text citations (character strings) from text in R

Tags: r, regex, text, gsub, citations

I'm trying to write a function that would allow me to paste written text, and it would return a list of the in-text citations that were used in the writing. For example, this is what I currently have:

```
pull_cites<- function (text){
gsub("[\\(\\)]", "", regmatches(text, gregexpr("\\(.*?\\)", text))[[1]])
    }
    
pull_cites("This is a test. I only want to select the (cites) in parenthesis. I do not want it to return words in 
    parenthesis that do not have years attached, such as abbreviations (abbr). For example, citing (Smith 2010) is 
    something I would want to be returned. I would also want multiple citations returned separately such as 
    (Smith 2010; Jones 2001; Brown 2020). I would also want Cooper (2015) returned as Cooper 2015, and not just 2015.")
```

And in this example, it returns

```
[1] "cites"                              "abbr"                               "Smith 2010"                        
[4] "Smith 2010; Jones 2001; Brown 2020" "2015"
```

But I would want it to return something like:

```
[1] "Smith 2010"
[2] "Smith 2010"                
[3] "Jones 2001"
[4] "Brown 2020"
[5] "Cooper 2015"
```

Any ideas on how to make this function more specific? I am using R. Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm all of them contain 4 digits at the end? Like `...2000)`?

Comment: Yes, they would all be years, so they would all have 4 digits. Thanks

Comment: Just wonder if you can have input like `Graham Cooper (2020)`?

Comment: Do none of these situations occur? (Cooper 2010a ; Cooper 2010b) (Same author, same year, but different publication), Cooper and Smith (2010) (Two authors), Cooper et al. (2010) (Multiple authors)

Comment: Yes, those situations could occur as well. Thanks for bringing that up! I wouldn't have a first and land name @Wiktor Stribizew, but two the situations that Merijin brought up could be likely

Comment: Look into APA style and others to see the syntax. Some more APA variations: "Cooper (2010a) and Cooper (2010b) are both the same author and published in 2010 two different publications. We can make it a bit harder with A. Smith (2011) and B. Smith (2011) who are nephews and love to publish on the same topic. More complex it becomes with groups (Jones, Smith, Liu, et al., 2020; Jones, Smith, Ruiz, et al., 2020) where you expand till you get unique prior to et al. usage. Let's write a lot of papers (Cooper, 2010b, 2011, 2012, in press; Jones & Adam, 2015)."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use

```r
x <- "This is a test. I only want to select the (cites) in parenthesis. I do not want it to return words in parenthesis that do not have years attached, such as abbreviations (abbr). For example, citing (Smith 2010) is something I would want to be returned. I would also want multiple citations returned separately such as (Smith 2010; Jones 2001; Brown 2020). I would also want Cooper (2015) returned as Cooper 2015, and not just 2015."
rx <- "(?:\\b(\\p{Lu}\\w*(?:\\s+\\p{Lu}\\w*)*))?\\s*\\(([^()]*\\d{4})\\)"
library(stringr)
res <- str_match_all(x, rx)
result <- lapply(res, function(z) {ifelse(!is.na(z[,2]) & str_detect(z[,3],"^\\d+$"), paste(trimws(z[,2]),  trimws(z[,3])), z[,3])})    
unlist(sapply(result, function(z) strsplit(paste(z, collapse=";"), "\\s*;\\s*")))
## -> [1] "Smith 2010"  "Smith 2010"  "Jones 2001"  "Brown 2020"  "Cooper 2015"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/i4pov5) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6ZXDEg/1).

The regex matches

- `(?:\b(\p{Lu}\w*(?:\s+\p{Lu}\w*)*))?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\b` - a word boundary
  - `(\p{Lu}\w*(?:\s+\p{Lu}\w*)*)` - Group 1: an uppercase letter followed with zero or more word chars, and then zero or more sequences of one or more whitespaces and then an uppercase letter followed with zero or more word chars
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `([^()]*\d{4})` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then four digits
- `\)` - a `)` char.

The `str_match_all(x, rx)` function finds all matches and keeps the captured substrings. Then, the Group 2 and 3 values are concatenated if Group 2 is not NA and Group 3 is all digits, else, the match is used as is. Later, the items in the `res` variable are joined with a `;` char and split with `;` (enclosed with any zero or more whitespaces).

Comment: Stribizew how would I go about changing the "group 1" portion of your code so that it instead searched for an uppercase letter followed with zero or more word chars, and then "et al."? for example, searching for Smith et al. (2011) and returning "Smith et al. 2011" instead of just (2011)?

Comment: @Jamie_B `(?:\b(\p{Lu}\w*(?:\s+\p{Lu}\w*)*)(?:\s+et\s+al\.)?)?\s*\(([^()]*\d{4})\)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/6ZXDEg/3). `(?:\s+et\s+al\.)?` is an optional non-capturing group that matches an optional sequence of 1+ whitespaces, `et`, 1+ whitespaces, `al.`.

Comment: thanks. I got an error that says "Error: '\p' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""(?:\b(\p"" but if I went back through and put an extra "\" like you had in the original answer, it ran without error. However, the result I am getting is Smith 2011 (in this example) and the result is not including the "et al." as part of the returned result. I'm assuming the result<- line of code needs to be changed? Thanks for your help, I am very new to Regex

Comment: @Jamie_B See [this R demo](https://ideone.com/lX8QBw).

Answer (score 7):

With some not-so-difficult regex, we can do the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

pull_cites <- function (text) {
  str_extract_all(text, "(?<=\\()[A-Z][a-z][^()]* [12][0-9]{3}(?=\\))|[A-Z][a-z]+ \\([12][0-9]{3}[^()]*", simplify = T) %>% 
    gsub("\\(", "", .) %>% 
    str_split(., "; ") %>% 
    unlist()
}

pull_cites("This is a test. I only want to select the (cites) in parenthesis. 
            I do not want it to return words in parenthesis that do not have years attached, 
            such as abbreviations (abbr). For example, citing (Smith 2010) is something I would 
            want to be returned. I would also want multiple citations returned separately such 
            as (Smith 2010; Jones 2001; Brown 2020). I would also want Cooper (2015) returned 
            as Cooper 2015, and not just 2015. other aspects of life 
            history (Nye et al. 2010; Runge et al. 2010; Lesser 2016). In the Gulf of Maine, 
            annual sea surface temperature (SST) averages have increased a total of roughly 1.6 °C 
            since 1895 (Fernandez et al. 2020)")

[1] "Smith 2010"            "Smith 2010"           
[3] "Jones 2001"            "Brown 2020"           
[5] "Cooper 2015"           "Nye et al. 2010"      
[7] "Runge et al. 2010"     "Lesser 2016"          
[9] "Fernandez et al. 2020"
```

Regex explanation within `str_extract_all()`:

- `(?<=\\()` matches one character after open bracket `(` (double escape `\\` in R)
- `[A-Z][a-z][^()]*` matches one capital letter followed by one lower case letter followed by one or more character(s) that is not brackets (`[^()*]` is contributed by @WiktorStribiżew)
- `(?=\\))` matches one character before a closing bracket `)`
- `[12][0-9]{3}` matches year, where I assume year would start with either 1 or 2 and followed by 3 more digits

The following regex is to match the special case with pattern `Copper (2015)`:

- `[A-Z][a-z]+ \\([12][0-9]{3}[^()]*` matches anything that has a capital letter followed by more than 1 lower case letter(s) followed by an empty space followed by an open bracket `(` followed by "year" that I defined above

Comment: Would be nice if you added `library(stringr)` as `str_extract_all()` is included in that package.

Comment: "*`[A-Z][a-z].+` matches one capital letter followed by one or more lower case letter(s)*" - no, this matches an uppercase letter, then a lowercase letter, and then one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

Comment: After testing this function on some of my pieces of writing, I came across some issues. For example, when pasting the sentences "...other aspects of life history (Nye et al. 2010; Runge et al. 2010; Lesser 2016). In the Gulf of Maine, annual sea surface temperature (SST) averages have increased a total of roughly 1.6 °C since 1895 (Fernandez et al. 2020)."     returns    [1] "Nye et al. 2010"  " Runge et al. 2010"  " Lesser 2016). In the Gulf of Maine, annual sea surface temperature SST) averages have increased a total of roughly 1.6 °C since 1895 Fernandez et al. 2020"

Comment: Thank you for your correction! A bit messy when writing the explanation. Fixed now :) @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @Jamie_B see if my updated code works, I forget to include a question mark `?` in the regex to avoid greedy match. The output would be something like `[1] "Nye et al. 2010" "Runge et al. 2010"  "Lesser 2016" "Fernandez et al. 2020"`

Comment: @benson23 You are matching inside parentheses, so instead of `.+?` it is more efficient to use `[^()]*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for the tip! May I ask what do you mean by "more efficient"? Based on `microbenchmark` results, `.+?` is consistently faster than `[^()]*`. Do you mean it's more logically correct to use `[^()]*`?

Comment: Yeah, it will keep the match in between parentheses.

Comment: @benson23 I tried the updated code I believe, but I am still getting the same result of Lesser 206 not being extracted properly from the text, or separated form Fernandez et al. 2020

Comment: @benson23 I got it to work after including [^()]* after [A-Z][a-z]. Could you update your original answer though? In your answer, you are still using ".+"